# Limiting reddit scraping to a view posts a day

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, sentiment-analysis, reddit

### Code used for scraping reddit data

```
posts = []
after = None

for a in range (7000):
    if after == None:
        current_url = url
    else:
        current_url = url + '?after=' + after # to request from a new URL after the first 25 posts 
    print(current_url)
    res = requests.get(current_url, headers={'User-agent': 'Final Year'})
    
    if res.status_code != 200:
        print('Status error', res.status_code)
        break # to break from the code if the request status code is not 200
    
    # go through every post in the JSON format request and add each post into the list 'posts'
    current_dict = res.json()
    current_posts = [p['data'] for p in current_dict['data']['children']]
    posts.extend(current_posts)
    after = current_dict['data']['after']
    
    # generate a random sleep duration to look more 'natural'
    sleep_duration = random.randint(2,6)
    print(sleep_duration)
    time.sleep(sleep_duration)
pd.DataFrame(posts).to_csv('../Data/CryptoCurrencyTrading.csv', index = False)
```

**The problem is that I am scrapping thousands of posts from one day which is not necessary. All I want is a certain amount of posts for one day.**

**Does reddit have a blocker to how far back you can scrape?**

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Any link to a solution is greatly appreciated also thanks.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/ - it mentions about limit here.

Comment: Any alternative solutions or functions would be appreciated also.